# How to change default "Create" label?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I want to change the '**Create**' label for a specific Content type.
I made a new content type called 'Bid Offer':

[image]

I want to show this to the users as '***Make Bid Offer***' instead of '**Create Bid Offer**'

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code into a custom module.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'bid_offer_node_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Make Bid Offer');
  }
}
```

or

```
function mymodule_form_bid_offer_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Make Bid Offer');
}
```

To change the URL, you can just set a path alias and alias *node/add/bid-offer* to *make-offer* or whatever you fancy should you need to.

Just for reference:

[`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

[`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)

**EDIT**

Following on from your comment, please try the following code (I've used it recently so I know it works):

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'bid_offer_node_form') {
    drupal_set_title(t('Make Offer'));
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Make Bid Offer');
  }
}
```

or

```
function mymodule_form_bid_offer_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    drupal_set_title(t('Make Offer'));
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Make Bid Offer');
}
```

Reference:

[`drupal_set_title()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7)

Comment: thx, but I needed to change the Title Label instead of the Submit button. http://i39.tinypic.com/2d291md.png

Comment: @wallace740 sorry for the late reply - I've edited my answer so it will now do what you need!  I've left everything else there just inc ase it helps anyone else :-)

Comment: Thx a lot @Chapabu, this is exactly what I was looking for ! cheers :-)

Answer (score -1):

Create bid_offer module with title callback returning node form. It should look like this (I didn't check it live!)

```
function bid_offer_menu_alter(&$items) {
  unset($items['node/add/bid_offer']); //unset core add path
}

function bid_offer_menu() {
   $items = array();
   $items['create/bid_offer'] = array(
     'title' => 'Create bid offer',
     'title callback' => 'bid_offer_title',
     'title arguments' => array(1),
     'page callback' => 'bid_offer',
     'page arguments' => array(1),
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     'access callback' => TRUE // You can customize this
   );


function bid_offer_title($type) {
  drupal_set_title(t('Make bid offer'));
  }
  return t();
}

function bid_offer($type = null) {
     if($type->type == 'bid_offer') {
       module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
       global $user;
       $new_node = new stdClass;
       $new_node->type = 'bid_offer';
       $new_node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; //localization
       $new_node->user = $user->uid;
       $new_node->name = (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : '');
       $form = drupal_get_form('bid_offer_form', $new_node);
       return $form;
     }
   return drupal_not_found();
}
```

After that you're be able to create your bids from http://yoursite/create/bid_offer

You can change

```
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
```

to MENU_NORMAL_ITEM for visible menu.

**Important! Do not afraid of creating module. I'm not developer, just Drupal enthusiast and if you think logically you can make it.**

Comment: I'm trying to create my module but I can't find "Create Bid Offer" label in my Node/Add form. http://i44.tinypic.com/283wh1.png

Comment: I could not find the appropriate array element to change it :(   I copied the array to here http://jsfiddle.net/5jWf7/ 
Can you look at it if you have time? 
http://i44.tinypic.com/283wh1.png

Comment: I wouldn't unset the node/add path.  Just add an alias to said path.

Comment: This is actually MASSIVELY over complicated for the question at hand.